# Two groups are isomorphic imply their group algebras are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Is this statement true?
>
> Let $G$ and $H$ be a group, and $G \cong H$. Then $\mathbb C G \cong
>  \mathbb C H$?

For example I want to show that $\mathbb C G \cong \mathbb C H$ where

$$\begin{align*} 
G = ~ &\bigl\langle x,y\ \mid \ xyx=yxy\bigr\rangle\\
H = ~ &\bigl\langle a,b\ \mid \ a^2=b^3\bigr\rangle
\end{align*}$$

Than I just need to show ($G \cong H$ which O know how to do).

Comment: Yes. Taking group algebras is a functor, and any functor sends isomorphisms to isomorphisms.

Answer (score 6):

Qiaochu's comment is right, but I don't want people to get the impression that one needs to know what a functor is in order to answer this question.  If $f:G\to H$ is an isomorphism, then you can define an isomorphism $\hat f:\mathbb CG\to\mathbb CH$ by 
$$
\hat f\left(\sum_ic_ig_i\right)=\sum_ic_if(g_i)
$$ 
for all coefficients $c_i\in\mathbb C$ and all group elements $g_i\in G$.  It is straightforward to check that $\hat f$ is an isomorphism of algebras over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: That's what it means for taking group algebras to be a functor!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I almost agree; the only quibble is that I described a functor only on the subcategory of groups and isomorphisms (which is enough for this problem but not for a reasonable functorial view of group algebras).  But the point of my answer is that people who've never heard of functors (and I conjecture the OP is such a person) can solve the problem without first learning what a functor is. With luck, someone might use my answer and your comment on it as a first step toward learning about functors.

Comment: Just a further question, the converse doesn't hold right?

Comment: @Andreas: your description of $\hat{f}$ makes no use of the fact that $f$ is an isomorphism! In any case, the reason my comment wasn't posted as an answer is that it wasn't an answer. I'm in no way saying that this answer was redundant.

Comment: @SamC: yes. For example, if $G$ is a finite group, the isomorphism type of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ only knows the dimensions of the complex irreducible representations of $G$ (by Maschke's theorem + the Artin-Wedderburn theorem), so for example $\mathbb{C}[Q_8] \cong \mathbb{C}[D_4]$.